# PHP, Mysql Notification Server Requirements

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, notifications, push

I am creating a project management system and in need to do push notifications when an activity took place.

**Question :** If I do a jquery to refresh and fetch notification from mysql database, say every 30seconds, will there be a huge impact in the server? What are the minimum requirements?

So basically, I'm looking at 10 notifications/day for 20 employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about an AJAX request to the server in order to update DOM elements, most basic web servers would very much be able to handle a few requests every 30 seconds or so. More important is how well-optimized the server-side code that finds & returns the notifications is. Assuming you'll have a few clients requesting every 30 seconds, I would suggest making sure the code only takes a few seconds to process the request and respond with the updated data.

Comment: The code will be a simple where it just queries a single table with 4 columns - id, memberid, status and url. That simple enough to handle? By most basic web servers, can you give me an example?

Comment: @thewebyogi Yup, queries take milliseconds to execute. The most popular web servers are Apache2 and Nginx servers. Each have their own system requirements, and should be reviewed before installing and configuring. In general a few GB of storage and 100MB of free memory should be more than enough.